# Proving that the function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $(X,μ_1)$ ,$(X,μ_2)$ ,$(Y,Ω_1)$ ,$(Y, Ω_2)$ Topological spaces.

Let $μ_2$ , $Ω_2$ be finer than $μ_1$ ,$Ω_1$ (that means: $μ_1\subsetμ_2$ ,  $Ω_1\subsetΩ_2$.

> Assume that $f :(X,μ_1)\to (Y,Ω_2)$ is continuous.
>   Prove that:
>
> 1. $f : (X,μ_2) \to (Y,Ω_2)$ is a continuous function.
> 2. $f : (X,μ_1)\to(Y,Ω_1)$ is a continuous function.

In 1 I said: the given f is continuous therefore acording to the definition , for every $U \inΩ_2$, $f^{-1}(U) \in μ_1$.

We know that $μ_1\subsetμ_2$ then $f^{-1}(U) \in μ_2$. So according to the definition of a continuous function we get that $g$ is continuous.
 Is that right?

In 2 i did not succeed in connecting between definitions , 1 and what is given.

Comment: Are $g$ and $h$ just $f$ but considering the spaces with different topologies?

Both should be the same idea. Playing games like "I know some set is open in one topology by the continuity assumptions, so the same set must be open under a different topology by the fineness assumptions"

Comment: Yes, g and h are just f.

Comment: $\mu_1 \subset \mu_2$ means that $\mu_1$ is *coarser* than $\mu_2$.

Comment: But now the thing you should prove need not hold. With $\mu_1 \subset \mu_2$ and $\Omega_1 \subset \Omega_2$ it holds, with the reversed inclusions it generally doesn't.

Comment: It is correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f: (X,\mu) \to (Y,\Omega)$ is continuous, you can replace the domain topology by a larger (finer) one, and $f$ stays continuous, or you can replace the codomain topology by a coarser one and $f$ stays continuous. Going the other way, can kill the continuity of $f$. The proof of the first two statements are obvious: $O \in \Omega$ implies $f^{-1}[O]\in \mu$ so $f^{-1}[O] \in \mu'$ in the case of a finer $\mu'$, and $O \in \Omega'$ implies $O \in \Omega$ (in the case of a coarser $\Omega'$) hence $f^{-1}[O] \in \mu$.

Comment: Thanks..Now i notice that: for every $O\inΩ_1$ , $O\inΩ_2$ and according to the continuity of the given f we get that $f^{-1}(O)\inμ_1$ , that what you mean?

Comment: @Al00ma that’s the idea